# laravel api return null

Tags: mysql, laravel, api

i have api that returns my data. i have a conditions that if visible==1 then return data otherwise don't return any thing.

but what i have receive is this

```
{
    "data": [null, {
        "order": 2,
        "path": "http:\/\/controlpanel.test\/uploads\/7bb61115dd77823d8e8e3f2b6afa401b.png",
        "visible": 1
    }]
}
```

i want this to be return

```
{
    "data": [{
        "order": 2,
        "path": "http:\/\/controlpanel.test\/uploads\/7bb61115dd77823d8e8e3f2b6afa401b.png",
        "visible": 1
    }]
}
```

without null.
this is my code

```
if($this->visible==1){
        return [

            'order' =>$this->order,
            'path' => asset('uploads').'/' . $this->path,
            'visible'=> $this->visible,
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Is it `post_id` or `posts_id`? You code uses `post_id` but your MySQL error message say `posts_id`.

Comment: its post_id in MySQL also ..

Comment: field value which you want to select column data is not available in tabel

Comment: solve it by having defining foreign key in comments and post function

Answer (score 0):

You need to define FK for `post()` relation in your comments model like

```
public function post(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Posts' , 'post_id');
}
```

Using `App\Posts` name convention laravel is looking for `posts_id` not `post_id`

update your post model also as

```
public function comments(){

    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'post_id');

}
```

Comment: not working. it seems that the problem is here in posts module.                              public function comments(){


        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');


    }

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH,  i was stuck for days :)

Answer (score 0):

You have Posts model so while in relation, it search for posts_id in the table attribute.
you can solve the problem using either of the following

1. update the comment module

   `public function post(){
           return $this->belongsTo(Posts::class , 'post_id');
       }`
2. Update the model name

`from Posts to Post`